# how to modify HttpRequest body parameters in a HttpFilter

Tags: java, groovy, micronaut

I am using Micronaut HttpFilter to intercept requests and one of the request body parameters.

Here is what I tried so far, but I am unable to get request body parameters in the interceptor.

The intent here is to check the `url` body parameter and if it does not match the whitelisted domain name, then replace the `url` body parameter with the whitelisted domain name.

Interceptor class

```
package com.aabingunz.web

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequestWrapper
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Filter
import io.micronaut.http.filter.FilterChain
import io.micronaut.http.filter.HttpFilter
import io.micronaut.http.netty.NettyHttpHeaders
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher

@Filter('/**')
class RequestInterceptor implements HttpFilter {

    private final JsonSlurper mapper = new JsonSlurper()

    @Override
    Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, FilterChain chain) {
        request = new HttpRequestWrapper<?>(request)
        NettyHttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders()

        /**
        * Intercept headers
        */
        String tokenHeader = headers.get("token")
        println "Reached inside RequestInterceper tokenHeader: " + tokenHeader

        /**
        * Intercept body params
        */
        Optional<String> body = request.getBody(String.class)
        def params = mapper.parseText(body.get())

        /**
        * TO-DO: Valdate and modify url body parameter
        */

        println "Inside RequestInterceper tokenHeader: " + tokenHeader
        println "Inside RequestInterceper body params: " + params

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
package com.aabingunz.web

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Nullable
import io.micronaut.http.HttpHeaders
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Consumes;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces


@Controller("/base/api/v1")
class BaseController {

    @Get(uri="/get/example", produces="text/plain")
    String index() {
        return "Example Response"
    }
    @Post("/post/example")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    HttpResponse<String> postIndex(@Nullable @Body String payload, HttpRequest<?> request) {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = request.getHeaders()
        String token = httpHeaders.get('token').toString()

        println "Inside BaseController body payload: " + payload
        println "Inside BaseController tokenHeader: " + token

        String results = "{'tokenHeader':"+token+"}"
        return HttpResponse.ok(results)
    }

}
```

Postman/Curl request

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/base/api/v1/post/example' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'token: 5678' \
--data-raw '{
    "userId": "aabingunz",
    "url": "http://hacker-domain.com"
}'
```

Output (RequestInterceptor `body.get()` gives `No value present`)

```
09:24:13.369 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 3124ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
Reached inside RequestInterceper tokenHeader: 5678
09:25:17.617 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: No value present
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at java_util_Optional$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at com.aabingunz.web.RequestInterceptor.doFilter(RequestInterceptor.groovy:33)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.filterPublisher(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:2106)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.buildResultEmitter(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1432)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.executeRoute(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1109)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:775)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:606)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.channelRead(HandlerPublisher.java:351)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:255)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:123)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:200)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:162)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Reached inside RequestInterceper tokenHeader: 5678
```

Using [Micronaut v2.5.1](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/tree/v2.5.1)

Comment: Does your filter run? Does it print anything?

Comment: @Renato Yes, the filter is working if I remove 2 statements below `Intercept body params`  comment. I have updated my question with output.

Comment: GET requests have no body. Also, even if they do, it doesn't mean the body is JSON... you should check the method is `POST` (or whatever method you're using) AND the `Content-Type` includes `application/json`.

Comment: @Renato: I am making a POST request (curl command present in my question) which has the required body params. Also the doFilter method is generic and it is able to capture both GET and POST requests (including json body), because it was able to reach my controller and after getting intercepted by the RequestInterceptor and the json data was accessible by  the controller. Only after I added the 2 statements after `Intercept body params` comment that this flow stopped working.

Comment: @Renato: Do you have any example on how to capture and modify the body params in doFilter using HttpRequest or extending HttpRequestWrapper to read and modify existing requests?

Comment: no sorry, but someone answered your question and it seems it's impossible to do this... check the 2.5 release notes: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because of this [breaking changes](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#breaks)

```
In Micronaut 2.5 the body will not be read until after filters are executed.
This may lead to cases where the body was available in a filter and is no longer available.
```